# How can I align a form label to the right of the control in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I align a form label to the right of the form control in Bootstrap 4.0, as per the "rooms" or "people" labels below:

[image]

Using the code below, it just comes out underneath:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="roomsno">meeting rooms required</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="roomsno" class="form-control col-md-4" type="number" />           
    <span>rooms</span>      
</div>
```

Here is my current code as a JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmg196/b4nqd5a6/4/

Comment: *"Using the code below, it just comes out underneath"* -- no, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post all of the form code please

Comment: I've added the full code to a JSFiddle

Comment: @WebDevBooster Sorry I still had a 'hack" in there of using a form-group div, but that messes with the rendering of corners on the text input.

Comment: So, all fixed now? (just had a look at your jsfiddle but there isn't much to see...)

Comment: BTW, you can post **all** of your code in your question. Clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon allows posting all "JavaScript/HTML/CSS".

Comment: No not fixed... Still stuck with this one. My JSfiddle still demo's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. there are a lot of ways to do that.
The one which I think better suits here is

add `display: flex` to the css for form-group class

For your jsfiddle example

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>number of delegates</label>
      <div class="form-group1">
        <input type="textbox" ID="e1" class="form-control col-md-2" type="number" />
        <span> people</span>

      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .form-group1 {
      display: flex
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ml-auto to the label class attribute

```
<label class=“ml-auto”>
```

Comment: <label class=“ml-auto”>

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a text-align: leftstyle to .control-label.

Because bootstrap gives labels within horizontal forms the text align style using the selector .form-horizontal .control-label, you need to use the same or a more specific selector:

.form-horizontal .control-label{ text-align: left !important; }

OR

Just add inline style="text-align: left" to your label.

Use "!important", if you need it to overwrite some default style to this.

Thanks!